# JSON.stringify extra quotes

Tags: javascript, json

Consider:

```
var d = new Date();
var j = d.toJSON();
var s = JSON.stringify(d);
```

console.log for each of the variables returns:

```
Tue Jul 29 2014 13:27:19 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
2014-07-29T11:27:19.253Z // a string
"2014-07-29T11:27:19.253Z" // same string as above but packed in ""
```

I expected them to return the same thing, but then I read

http://www.json.org/js.html:

> If the stringify method sees an object that contains a toJSON method,
>   it calls that method, and stringifies the value returned. This allows
>   an object to determine its own JSON representation.

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify:

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value
>   is a function, then the toJSON method customizes JSON stringification
>   behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned
>   by the toJSON method when called will be serialized. For example:

Does this mean that I always have to do something like:

```
var d = new Date();
var j = d.toJSON();
var s;

if (d.toJSON) {
    s = d.toJSON();
} else {
    s = JSON.stringify(d);
}
```

to ensure that s == j, since I can't rely on JSON.stringify not performing two serialisations?

**EDIT**

In light of jgillich's answer, the following code helps clarify things (for me at least):

```
var s = "xxx"
s = JSON.stringify(s)
s = JSON.stringify(s)
s = JSON.stringify(s)
s = JSON.stringify(s)
s = JSON.stringify(s)
console.log(s)
```

returns:

```
""\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"xxx\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\"""
```

i.e. JSON.stringify returns not a string representation but rather a serialisation of an object. You'd think I'd realise that from the name and the presence of toString.

Comment: I don't see the problem. In JSON, strings are enclosed in quotes. If you try to parse `2014-07-29T11:27:19.253Z` without quotes, you'll get an error.

Comment: The problem is: "2014-07-29T11:27:19.253Z" != ""2014-07-29T11:27:19.253Z""

Comment: JSON isn't supposed to be equal to the original data. You have to call `JSON.parse()` to undo `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @MattJacobsen `2014-07-29T11:27:19.253Z` is just a string; `"2014-07-29T11:27:19.253Z"` is JSON (=string) that contains a string.

Comment: @jgillich I was expecting behaviour similar to calling toString on a string, ie just return the object as is, as it's already a string, and not stick more quotes around it. Your answer and these comments have clarified things for me: toJSON is not meant to be viewed as being another name for toString ;-)

Comment: toJSON basically is another name to toString, to be specific another name to toISOString(). The problem is that JSON.stringify when run on a string (*on any string*), puts extra quotes around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toJSON()` is not a function that is meant to return JSON. Instead, it is a function that, when it exists, is called **before** the JSON serialization happens. The following are exactly the same:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date().toJSON()); // toJSON called manually
JSON.stringify(new Date()); // toJSON called by the serializer
```